# WPF Cascading Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Topic: How to prevent that the binding on a UserControl overrides the binding given by the upper (Main)Window using this UserControl.

I already read posts, and some books on that subject but I am still puzzled with binding mechanisms.
Even in some specialized books the terms of *DependencyProperty* or *AttachedProperty* is barely mentioned.
Microsoft documentation is good but somewhat bare.

This example is an extreme simplification of the BasketballRoster MVVM example of Head First C#

I have a **usercontrol**, a simple *circle*

```
...  
xmlns:vm_nmspc="clr-namespace:BindingMCVE.ViewModel" >
             
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm_nmspc:my_usercontrol_vm x:Key="MyUserControlVM"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel  DataContext="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyUserControlVM}" Height="100"  Width="100">
        <Ellipse Fill="{Binding my_color}" Height="50" Width="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And what I like is to provide a **parameterless contructor** *my_usercontrol_vm()* so that I can view my circle **filled with red** while I am working on the view of my UserControl.

[image: UserControl alone]

For that I use an instance of the *class* my_usercontrol_vm inside the **UserControlResources**.
Here I use the *DynamicResource* keyword ( I had first tested StaticResource )

```
class my_usercontrol_vm
{
    public string my_color {get; set;}

    public my_usercontrol_vm() : this("Red") { }

    public my_usercontrol_vm(string color)
    {
        my_color = color;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use several UserControl inside a (Main)Window, still **using  binding** to see in *"real time"* the evolution of my view.

```
xmlns:vm_nmspc="clr-namespace:BindingMCVE.ViewModel" >

<Window.Resources>
    <vm_nmspc:main_window_vm x:Key="MainWindowVM"/>   
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainWindowVM}">
        
        <view_nmspc:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding usr_ctrl_1}"/>
        <view_nmspc:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding usr_ctrl_2}"/>
        
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And the *ViewModel* class dedicated to the MainWindow

```
class main_window_vm
{
    public my_usercontrol_vm usr_ctrl_1 { get; set; }
    public my_usercontrol_vm usr_ctrl_2 { get; set; }

    public main_window_vm()
    {
        usr_ctrl_1 = new my_usercontrol_vm("Green");
        usr_ctrl_2 = new my_usercontrol_vm("Blue");
    }
}
```

Note that I am **expecting** to see **GREEN** and **BLUE** filled circles.

However what I get is *red* circles

[image]

I would have got green and blue circle I had not put a resource inside the UserControl

While using the debugger I can see that I am entering first the constructor of the class *main_window_vm* and after (2 times) the one of the class *my_user_control_vm*, so that both circles are finally red.

I know that at the present time I am maybe 10% aware of WPF but I thought that this way of doing would have been quite right. As last I am requesting that inside the MainWindow the *UserControl1* control *be bind* to the property usr_ctrl_X of the class *main_window_vm*

Any advice welcome.

Best Regards.

NGI

Comment: A companion question (if you do not come from this question) [conditional-resources-creation-wpf-xaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279584/conditional-resources-creation-wpf-xaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `DataContext` of your `UserControl`, but this isn't used by your `Ellipse` as this inherits the `DataContext` of the `StackPanel`.  This doesn't change and will always be bound to your `MyUserControlVM` resource.

You should remove `DataContext="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyUserControlVM}"` from the `StackPanel`.  If you add this to the `UserControl` then your binding should overwrite it.  You could also use the blend design namespaces to set a design `DataContext` that would only be used at design time.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of Charles Mager ( many thanks ), I post a reply on my own question so that everyone has the answer illustrated.

So charles adviced to put the **DataContext** into the *UserControl* and not the *StackPanel*

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingMCVE.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100"
    xmlns:vm_nmspc="clr-namespace:BindingMCVE.ViewModel"             
    DataContext="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyUserControlVM}"  >
    <!--DataContext added above-->

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm_nmspc:my_usercontrol_vm x:Key="MyUserControlVM"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <!--DataContext removed from StackPanel below-->
    <StackPanel  Height="100"  Width="100">
        <Ellipse  Fill="{Binding my_color}" Height="50" Width="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here it is:

[image]
[image]

Comment: self comment: Note that it works with the keyword *DynamicResource* and not with the keyword *StaticResource*