# Conditional Resources Creation WPF XAML Design / Run time

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datacontext, resourcedictionary

Following a first question on  [WPF Cascading Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560927/wpf-cascading-binding),

I remarked that I had **more Resources than desired** defined in both the **MainWindow** and the **UserControls**:

This is well seen in **Snoop**

[image: bindingMCVE snoop view]

- the **MainWindow XAML** has an "instance" of a MainWindow ViewModel that paints the 2 usercontrol in *green* and *blue*

[image: Test application of 2 UserControls]

- additionnaly there are 2 instances of usercontrol viewmodels for each of the 2 UserControls that would paint the inner circle in *red*

[image: simple usercontrol]

1. My first Intention in the **Usercontrol** was to be able to see "*live*" how my control would look like ( I painted it red to distinguish this "model" from the green and blue circles in the Main Window)
2. My **Resources** are very cheap to create, so no matter if I have 2 extra resources that are still living in my application, but I would anticipate the time where my Resources will be more expensive...

**Finally** my question is :

How can I conditionnaly let Resources be created in "low level" control ( so that I can have a preview in the view of the control ) **but** prevent this creation when running the full application ( or the view of the Main Window ) because I will bind to the Resources of this upper level.

Many thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

NGI

Comment: One item during design time and latter during running?

Comment: @ Maximus : the UserControl Resource will be only needed during design time when designing the look and feel of this UserControl ( circle is red ). During design time of the MainWindow or during the running of the application, the MainWindow resource will impose its data ( the 2 circles are green and blue ) so that the UserControl Resources are wasted

Comment: @ Maximus: Hi, I found what I think to be an easier way to come to goal for my problem of wasted viewmodel resources in subcontrol when running the full application. Tell me what you think about the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will finally try to answer my own question

Result is as awaited **no "duplicate resources"** in the lower level ViewModel instances
The result in snoop:
[image: Snoop view. Only the mainwindow viewmodel instance]

The XAML code

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingMCVE.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingMCVE"
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm_nmspc:my_usercontrol_vm}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100"
         xmlns:vm_nmspc="clr-namespace:BindingMCVE.ViewModel"               
 >

<UserControl.Resources>
    <!--No resources created in XAML-->
</UserControl.Resources>


        <Grid>
    <StackPanel  Height="100"  Width="100">
        <Ellipse  Fill="{Binding my_color}" Height="50" Width="50" />
    </StackPanel>
    
</Grid>
```

Note the new line:

> d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm_nmspc:my_usercontrol_vm}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"

**And there is absolutely no other modifications !!**

The trick is to use the IDE to support you ( *if you are unaware of the syntax that should be used in the XAML* ).

I will try to illustrate what I did.

Choose your object, and in the format menu choose Set Design Time DataContext

[image: Set Design Time DataContext]

Then choose your DesignInstance ( *here the ViewModel my_usercontrol_vm*) and *do not forget* to tick *IsDesignTimeCreatable*

[image]

This created the *magic* line in the Ellipse declaration but I moved it on the top of the XAML.

So this answered my question. It is possible with no deep knowledge on WPF/XAML to make all your subviews (controls) "rendered" without the additional cost of wasted resources of viewmodels

To give echo to what Maximus gave in the first answer, I found also another post (will try to find it again and quote it in a next edit) using directly the function **DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode( )**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        if (  DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            //Do what you want here for design time specific actions
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prepared simplified way out displaying one data during design time and latter during run time. Hopefully you will find it useful and adjust to your case. 
**XAML:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DesignModeDataTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="Design mode"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RunTimeDataTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="Run Time"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:IsInDesignModeConverter x:Key="IsInDesignModeConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsInDesignModeConverter}">
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource DesignModeDataTemplate}"/>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource RunTimeDataTemplate}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

**Converter:**

```
 class IsInDesignModeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)(DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject)).DefaultValue))
            return values[0];
        return values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As a result it display Design mode text during design time and Run time when running.
In your case instead of TextBlock you can insert already defined resources.

Comment: @ Maximus : Many thanks for your reply. I just compiled it and saw the expected results. Let me some time to thoroughly understand it and to adapt it to my case