# Can not find WPF DesignInstance Object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Like mentioned in this post [Design / Run-time datacontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279584/conditional-resources-creation-wpf-xaml-design-run-time), I use design-time datacontext to "decorate" my (sub-window) *usercontrols* before collecting them in my *MainWindow* and thus avoid keeping resources at run-time

File *SampleItemWithRun.xaml*

```xaml
<UserControl
 ... 
 xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfAppCertif_1.ViewModel" x:Class="WpfAppCertif_1.Views.SampleItemWithRun"
 ...
 d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type ViewModel:CodeSample}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
 >
<Grid>
...
</Grid>
```

However I would like to access this *DesignInstance* in order to perform a small *adjustement* in the *usercontrol constructor*

File *SampleItemWithRun.xaml.cs*

I had like to write something like shown below but DataContext is null ( the same thing if I put the *d:DataContext...* line inside the  mark.
I checked under the debugger lots of fields of *this* object but did not find my *CodeSample* object

```C#
public partial class SampleItemWithRun : UserControl
{
    public SampleItemWithRun()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dc = DataContext; //Not working because Null !!
        var cs = dc as CodeSample;

        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            if ( null != cs)
            {
                //do something on the CodeSample object cs
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In conclusion the question is :
*Where can I find my design instance object ?*

Comment: Try to do that in `Loaded` event.

Comment: The code is effectively working in the Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { ...} callback. However I am more interested in having this code in the constructor. Because what I want is to have the design view of my UserControl  "decorated" with some default values. I am able to have most of this "decoration" working ( for example with ObservableCollection<> properties ) but I have a particular case that would require to go through the code that is written in my question ( and in a second step I will try to remove this particular case but it is out of topic here )

Comment: I'm 99% sure that the `DataContext` can't be set on an object until its fully constructed, so there is no way to run this code in the constructor.

Comment: @Ron Beyer : I tried on the debugger and effectively the DataContext property of the _this_ object ( UserControl ) seems to be set at the end of the constructor. I was able to enter the callback  `void Grid_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)` just after leaving the constructor. When adding my code inside this event, it unfortunately did not fulfill displaying something on my design view. So maybe you are right and it is not possible to do it that way

Comment: *I want is to have the design view of my UserControl "decorated" with some default values* - sounds like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). Why do you need that? For Blend? You know about MVVM? Bindings have `FallbackValue` which can set default value whenever ViewModel is not exists. But I never actually tried to create *fake* ViewModel to have View looks nice in design time (and moreover Blend is not my design tool).

Comment: @Sinatr : Yes what I do is typically a simple MVVM like  methodology ( see the declaration `... {x:Type ViewModel:CodeSample}...` I do no use Blend as I think some of the Blend features are now integrated in Visual Studio ( some years ago maybe). Don't mind the word _default_ I used. I had better to say _with some adequat (first test/preview) value_ . Having design views "decorated" is good ( otherwise you have to run your whole MainWindow ). See the link to my other questions (atop of this question ) for simple samples. In a near future I will have a look to other methodology ( IOC, DI ..; )

Comment: Try to put `throw new Exception()` into `Loaded` event handler or constructor of your `Window/UserControl`. Neither will get executed in design mode. It looks like this approach will only work for custom controls (e.g. inherited from `Control`). What works for sure is attached behavior, use one to attach a fake ViewModel. You can check for design mode in behavior code and attach nothing.